# Maven pom.xml missing dependency error: artifacts could not be resolved

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

This error won't go away even after many 'mvn clean install' and reimport pom.xml's

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project foo: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project be.foo:foo:jar:2.0-SNAPSHOT: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.neo4j:neo4j-spatial:jar:0.12-neo4j-2.0.4, 
diff_match_patch:diff_match_patch:jar:current:

Failure to find org.neo4j:neo4j-spatial:jar:0.12-neo4j-2.0.4 in 
https://repo.spring.io/libs-release was cached in the local repository,
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-releases has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

eventhough the pom clearly has the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>0.12-neo4j-2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Weirdest thing is I don't even think I need this in my project, it just started complaining about it.

So far I'm guessing that it has to do with some sort of version mismatch?

```
"diff_match_patch" etc
```

Comment: `mvn clean install -U`?

Comment: https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/ ... here, check for yourself which versions this repo supports and which version you requested ... // Edit: even mvnrepo doesn't know that version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-spatial ...

Comment: I have checked maven repository and I have not found such any versioned dependency. Change version. Link for your reference is : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-spatial

check it for versioning 0.12x

Comment: @Tom you are correct, please see my edit for further issues

Comment: Nope, SO doesn't support "evolving questions". If you have a new question, then create a new post. Or just add a proper repository for your dependencies ...

Comment: @Tom, but the underlying issue is the same? Maven is trying to download depencies that are not needed in the project and I don't know where it's being specified that they need to be added

Comment: It's still a different issues and maven only tries to load dependencies specified in the projects pom.xml or in a parent pom. So you should start looking there. If you think a dependency is not needed, then why don't you remove it from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the URL thart´s shown in your logs, you´ll see that library is not there. You probably need to change the version or set up a different repo.